# Passing Windows Command via Citrix Receiver with Mac (for show windows side-by-side shortuct)

Tags: macos, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, citrix-receiver

I have a Mac computer that I use to connect to a Windows 2012 server via Citrix Reciever 11.8. I would like to use the show windows side-by-side shortcut that is typically engaged by pressing the Windows key + right arrow key/left arrow key.

Unfortunately, this does not appear to work with the default configuration of Citrix Receiver 11.8. As such, I would like to know how to pass the Windows command key on Mac via Citrix Receiver 11.8 to permit the combination of Windows + right arrow key/left arrow key to use the show windows side-by-side shortcut.

Citrix permits the passing of the Windows/Apple key to the session but requires users to press Windows/Apple key + right arrow.  This will allow for the opening of the Start menu but precludes the shortcut for show windows side-by-side.

1. Does anyone know how to customize the Citrix shortcut to pass the required keys as described above?
2. Is there a way to customize the Windows command for the show windows side-by-side shortcut?

Thanks,